# Same class different id in same function to avoid extra code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two jquery functions which are exactly the same with the only difference being the id.   What changes do I need to make in order to have one function serve for both cases?.  Using class selector by itself causes both to be selected at the same time.

The function - dropdown list on click, select by checkbox, display selection in the input box:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#location dt a").on('click', function() {
  $("#location dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$("#location dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $("#location dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $("#location dd ul").hide();
});

$('#location input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('#location').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('#loc').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('#location dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
});
```

The HTML

```
<label for="proptypes">Type</label>
<dl class="dropdown" id="proptypes"> 
    <dt>
        <a href="#"><p class="multiSel" id="prop"></p></a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </dd>
        </dl>
```

Please note that the function works but I am simply trying to reduce the amount of code - http://christamariebusuttil.com/homesmalta/  (function result is displayed in type and location input / select boxes)

Comment: Wrap it around a function with a param id and call it from the outside twice

Comment: Where are you calling the two IDs? I don't see any duplicate code in the example above. Also, considering your code already achieves the desired result, this question may be more suitable for [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: Also, `getSelectedValue` isn't even being called, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/0d2q3v61/

Wrap in a function.
And call it.

`var box1 = new multiSelectBox("#location", "#loc");`

```
function multiSelectBox(parentId, selectedId) {

  // 
  var _hideSelectionList = function() {
    $(parentId).find("dd ul").hide();
  };

  // hide selection list, on initialization
  _hideSelectionList();

  // 
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) 
        _hideSelectionList();
  });

  // 
  $(parentId).on('click', 'dt a', function() {
    $(parentId).find("dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  // retrieve checked items in string
  var _getCheckedItems = function() {
    var checkedItems = "";
    $(parentId).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            checkedItems += $(this).val() + ", ";
        }
      });

    return checkedItems;
  };

  // 
  $(parentId).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

    var selectedItem = $(this).val() + ",";
    $(selectedId).html(_getCheckedItems());

  });

}
```